# Adding an instruction to a multicycle datapath and control (MIPS)

Tags: controls, mips, state-machine

I have an assignment where I have to add an instruction of this form:

```
 liw <dstreg>,[<src1reg>+<src2reg>]
 e.g. liw $2,[$3+$4]
```

Where `liw` is similar to `lw`, `src1reg` and `src2reg` add together to get the memory address to be stored in `dstreg`. I was also supplied with this image, which states that I need to "modify the control for the multicycle implementation to add the instruction `liw`.

[image: Multicycle datapath to be modified]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Michael: I'm not sure where to begin with the problem. I don't believe I have to actually add any lines to the datapath to get the `liw` instruction to work, do I? It looks like there just need to be certain bits of the control active.

Comment: @Michael: Here is the complete PDF of my assignment, maybe that will help. The relevant question is question 3: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwe05alevmfw4xq/asg9_combined.pdf

Comment: @Michael: I'm fairly certain what I need to add to the finite state machine diagram, but I don't know about the multicycle datapath, or if I even am supposed to add anything.